# Angular animations not working

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to run entering animation for appearing elements on my page which are looped via *ngFor.
I've tried to use callback to figure out if these animations ever been launched and they were! But nothing was shown.

Currently my code looks so

```
<section
  class="row justify-content-center mb-2 mb-md-4"
  *ngFor="let site of sites"
  [@flyInOut]="'in'"
> ...some content </section>
```

And animations are next

```
animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-20%)'}),
        animate(100)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

No errors are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out Safari requires polyfills for animations and after adding them it works.